# Should optional views be added by storyboard/xib and then hidden or added programmatically? (Good practices)

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, xib

I'm starting a new project and I have some doubts about storyboard good practices, specifically about optional hidden views (show only under certain circumstances).

Let's say you have an pdf downloader app, when the user select a download button a UIProgress bar appears and show the download progress. Should this progress bar be included in the storyboard or generated programmatically when the user press the download button?

It's a simple example but what about if there isn't only a UIProgressBar but also multiple hidden (optional) buttons? What if some of the buttons are overlapped? (I know overlapped button is bad design but just for the purpose of exemplify)

Should this ones be hidden or added programmatically? What about performance? Some say it takes more time to parse a Storyboard/Xib than a programmatically build view.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In DonaldKnuth's paper "Structured Programming With GoTo Statements", he wrote: "Programmers waste enormous amounts of time thinking about, or worrying about, the speed of noncritical parts of their programs, and these attempts at efficiency actually have a strong negative impact when debugging and maintenance are considered. We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: **premature optimization is the root of all evil**. Yet we should not pass up our opportunities in that critical 3%."

---

So, you are trying to solve a performance problem **you do not really have (at the moment).**
You decision to have a view permanently or temporarily should be based on context of the view usage, not some hearsay performance issues between xib/stb vs programmatic approach, that resembles platform-wars, but otherwise, given how LLVM compiler works today, and what the HW performance of iPhone 4 or higher is, is basically nonsense.

Here's a simple rule. Have all the views in IB, hide or unhide them as necessary, and add/remove a view programatically **only if you can give a good reason why.**

I understand you instinctive desire to make it right, so instead of trying to manage one milion views in one controller, take a look at the problem that is satirically called **Massive View Controller.**

Proper decomposition into **custom views**, separation of concerns, clearly defined responsibilities split into more view controllers, **view controller containment**, is the answer to to address your concerns.

You want your app first and foremost to work **correctly**.That you can achieve by having a **sound architecture** so that you will be able to stay in control. Users will not appreciate that you instantiated some button programatically, because they couldn't care less. But if the app has inconsistent state because your view controller has 7000 lines and is spaghetti hell or is crashing, that is a problem.

Comment: Great answer.. I'll put more effort on things that actually matter

Answer (score 0):

if you are planning to use storyboards; would suggest to have view/buttons etc included . you can always hide / unhide the same from the code. 
have a thought process and not cluster your view. Have multiple views and make your app look neat